# How to insert a picture with latin1 Characters?

Tags: xetex

I would like in insert a picture in latex with a file contains latin1 characters, however i get an error
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,height=6cm]{images/Côte d'Ivoire_Pillar.eps}


\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: This is the error (images/Cte d’Ivoire_Pillar-eps-converted-to.pdf)

Comment: Is your tex system up-to-date? And does it work if you rename the eps and give it a name without spaces and non-ascii chars?

Comment: yes it is update and if i rename it, it will work

Comment: C\xf4te d'Ivoire_Pillar.eps... ie  non-ascii chars

Comment: Rename image so that it will not contain empty spaces.

Comment: show your log-file.

Comment: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.9.10)  8 APR 2021 11:38
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(/compile/main.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-07-17> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex
/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/5552465846vbmbmnzkhchh

Comment: at best convert the graphic once manually with epstopdf.

Comment: can you please explain in steps, so i could understand what you are suggesting